# Feedback loop in Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, pid-controller

I have a problem with writing Verilog HDL code. I want to design a simple PID controller in FPGA I am using Cyclone II family. I want to feedback my output value as an input in a previous stage of calculations. Equation looks like this u(n) = u(n-1) + x (x is calculated correctly) so I created a register to save the output value and connected it to a previous stage in my design.

Unfortunately this solution doesn't work when I simulate this I get 'unknown' value in the register that I am saving the output value to and the output value itself is also 'unknown' (by unknown I mean 'x').

Is it possible to create a feedback loop between certain components in HDL design? How can it be done? Should I try to resolve this issue by doing the calculations step by step in an FSM?

EDIT: This is my code as requested

**PID Module**

```
module pid(clk,rst_n,Kp_in, Kd_in, Ki_in,temp_data_in,setpoint,pwm_out);


parameter N = 8;
parameter M = 16;

input   clk;
input   rst_n;
input   [N-1:0]temp_data_in;
input   [N-1:0]setpoint;    
input [N-1:0]Kp_in;
input [N-1:0]Kd_in;
input [N-1:0]Ki_in;

output [N-1:0]pwm_out;

wire    clk;
wire    rst_n;

reg [N-1:0]temp_data_reg;
reg [N-1:0]setpoint_reg;
reg [N-1:0]pwm_out_reg;

localparam [1:0] idle = 2'b00, load = 2'b01, run= 2'b10;
localparam k = 2;

reg [1:0] state_reg, state_next;

always@(posedge clk, negedge rst_n) begin
    if(!rst_n) begin
        state_reg <= idle;
    end else
        state_reg <= state_next;
    end

reg sum_out_old_reg_en;

reg     [N-1:0]K0;
reg [N-1:0]K1;
reg [N-1:0]K2;

wire [N-1:0] ex0;
wire [N-1:0] ex1;
wire [N-1:0] ex2;

wire [2*N-1:0] out0;
wire [2*N-1:0] out1;
wire [2*N-1:0] out2;

wire [2*N-1:0] sum1;
wire [2*N-1:0] sum2;
wire [2*N-1:0] sum_out_old;
wire [2*N-1:0] sum_out;

register e0(clk,rst_n,(temp_data_in-setpoint),ex0);
register e1(clk,rst_n,ex0,ex1);
register e2(clk,rst_n,ex1,ex2);
mult u_mult1(ex0,K0,out0);
mult u_mult2(ex1,K1,out1);
mult u_mult3(ex2,K2,out2);
adder u_adder1(out0,out1,sum1);
adder u_adder2(out2,sum_out_old,sum2);
adder u_adder3(sum1,sum2,sum_out);  

register16b u_old(clk,rst_n,sum_out,sum_out_old);

always@(posedge clk) begin
    state_next = state_reg; 
    case(state_reg)
        idle: begin
                    state_next = load;
                end
        load: begin
                    K0 = Kp_in + Kd_in + Ki_in;
                    K1 = -Kp_in + (-2)*Kd_in;
                    K2 = Kd_in;         
                    state_next = run;
                end
        run: begin

                state_next = run;
              end
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Can you share your code? Did you specify an initial value for the holding register, or use a reset signal to put it in a known state at the start of your simulation?

Comment: Yes, the registers output value is 0 when reset is low.

Comment: And your simulation testbench sets reset low long enough to get all registers into a known state, but then you still see 'X' values reappear once you release `reset`? That sounds like you did everything right --- if you can, share your code and we can look for typo's or other kinds of problems.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you got the order of your inputs & outputs for instantiated blocks right? Without explicit connections (like `reg reg1 (.CLK(c), .RST(r), .I(x), .O(y))` ), there's no way I can be sure of this part of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any code that resets `K0`, `K1`, and `K2`, until the load state is used.

This means that on start-up, these registers have `X` value.

Therefore the outputs of `u_mult1`, `u_mult2`, and `u_mult3` have `X` value.

Therefore the outpus of `u_adder1`, `u_adder2`, and `u_adder3` get `X` value.

Therefore on the next clock edge, `sum_out_old` gets `X` value. Probably at the same time, the K variables get loaded with their values from the module inputs. But it's too late. Since `sum_out` is calculated from `sum_out_old`, it then becomes `X`, and `sum_out_old` is trapped in the `X` state.

The easy way to solve this is to have `K0`, `K1`, and `K2` reset to 0 when `rst_n` is asserted (low), but you should consider if this is correct for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

For simulation, you need to reset your values to a known state at the beginning. You can use the reset line for this, but this ends up synthesised as The Photon mentions (not usually a problem)

Another way to do it is to set the value when you code the register, such as:

```
reg [N-1:0]K0 = 8'b00000000;
reg [N-1:0]K1 = 8'b00000000;
reg [N-1:0]K2 = 8'b00000000;
```

Depending on your tools, this may or may not work (I use Xilinx tools), and actually may end up being synthesised (i.e. the registers are set during the bitstream being loaded into the FPGA) but give it a go and let us know.

Comment: My memory is that some version of Xilinx tools that I used once wouldn't respect this in synthesis. Because of that, I habitually don't code it this way. But I think it's good in recent tools.

Comment: Yes, I think you have the choice for it to synthesise now - In any case I just use it for simulation when I don't have a reset line (and I don't mind whether the synthesis tools respect it or not, as in most cases you don't mind what the register starts out at)